# Why there's no "descendingIterator ()" in SortedSet but it is in TreeSet?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

The fact that it hasn't been added yet to the interface makes me think there must be some valid reason. While I think that you shouldn't be passing sets around merrily and, hence, the implementation class will rarely appear in the interface of a class in case reverse iteration is needed, IMO it would improve the SortedSet interface nonetheless.

Comment: It is possible to have a sorted collection that does not support reverse traversal(for instance a single linked list which sorts on insertion.)

Comment: Don't assume there's a reason for the core Java API design. In many cases, it just wasn't thought out properly.

Comment: P.S. I suggest you turn this into an actual answerable question, else it's liable to get closed.

Comment: @skaffman, sorry, what?? where did I touch? :) How do I do that?

Comment: @skaffman I know that sometimes the design wasn't perfect, but this is a case where it could have been changed without consequences and surely someone thought about it before me.

Comment: @skaffman Ok got it, it's too general, well if it has to be closed let's that be it... it's as straightforward as I can put it.

Comment: Seems easily answerable to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`descendingIterator` was introduced in 1.6. `SortedSet` is an `interface` that was introduced in 1.2. You can't add methods to `interface`s (JDBC is "special").

In order to facilitate adding extra methods to a sorted set-like interface, 1.6 added the awkwardly named `NavigableSet` (and `NavigableMap`). This is a replacement for `SortedSet`. Old implementations should be retrofitted with this new interface.

Comment: Of course, silly me, you can't add methods to interfaces. Also, I didn't know NavigableSet was intended as an extension to SortedSet. Thanks, that was useful.

Comment: @Jubbat, if that were true, then all interfaces would be empty.

Comment: "**new** methods", better? :)

Comment: I think what you mean to say is that adding new methods to an interface without adding them to the implementation classes is not safe.

Comment: @SteveKuo You can't add method to all implementation classes in an open system.